# Problems with renewing certificates after ACME API upgrade to V2

Tags: lets-encrypt, acme.sh

We are using [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) to renew our let's encrypt certificates and ran into problems today.

First we got some errors and ran into the `rate limit for invalid requests` often and therefore decided to upgrade to V2 as it was recommended anyhow.

We upgraded by running `acme.sh --upgrade` and updated all the URL's in our domains config to use the new `v2` endpoints.

Now the `acme.sh --renew -d my.domain.at --ecc` runs further than before (we had some troubles where we couldn't get `nonce` because we were missing the `/directory` postfix in the `Le_API` variable.

Now we have the problem that we receive an unauthorized in our verification:

```
{
  "type": "http-01",
  "status": "invalid",
  "error": {
    "type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized",
    "detail": "Invalid response from https://my.domain.at/login [...]: \"\u003c!DOCTYPE html\u003e\\n\u003chtml\u003e\\n    \u003chead\u003e\\n        \u003cmeta http-equiv=\\\"X-UA-Compatible\\\" content=\\\"IE=edge\\\"/\u003e\\n        \u003cmeta charset=\\\"utf-8\\\"/\u003e\"",
    "status": 403
  },
  "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/11110584350/BRAIDw",
  "token": "my-hash",
  "validationRecord": [
    {
      "url": "http://my.domain.at/.well-known/acme-challenge/my-hash",
      "hostname": "my.domain.at",
      "port": "80",
      "addressesResolved": [
        "X.X.X.X",
        "..."
      ],
      "addressUsed": "..."
    },
    {
      "url": "https://my.domain.at/.well-known/acme-challenge/my-hash",
      "hostname": "my.domain.at",
      "port": "443",
      "addressesResolved": [
        "X.X.X.X",
        "..."
      ],
      "addressUsed": "..."
    },
    {
      "url": "https://my.domain.at/login",
      "hostname": "my.domain.at",
      "port": "443",
      "addressesResolved": [
        "X.X.X.X",
        "..."
      ],
      "addressUsed": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

We have an NGINX running and we are not sure what's happening here. We shouldn't be redirected to the `/login` page as far as we understood.

Are we missing anything? The certificate renewal always worked flawlessly until we ran into problems today and tried to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out our NGINX configuration was wrong, we configured the required route `.well-known/acme-challenge` to point to an empty folder and are asking ourselves now how that could have ever worked. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

After fixing the config in NGINX everything worked as expected.